# aws lambda python function to reboot ec2 instances not working

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, reboot

I have a Lambda function to reboot instances:

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = ec2.reboot_instances(
        InstanceIds=[
        'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ],
    )
    print(response)
```

It just refuses to work.

The response when I trigger it:

> {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId':
> '12994c92-98ab-4b62-bc10-a0e0b4881aaa', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
> 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid':
> '12994c92-98ab-4b62-bc10-a0e0b4881aaa', 'content-type':
> 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '231', 'date': 'Sun, 30
> Aug 2020 15:44:40 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

The interesting part: if I change ec2.reboot_instances to ec2.start_instances then it works.

So I am trying to find out why would a reboot command be refused and a start/stop command be accepted?

Note: I included the permission in IAM to reboot instances. The instance is a linux openvpn server AMI bundle

Comment: Are you sure its not working? Check CloudTrail to see if the API action is fired

Comment: So you've got 200 response can you kindly check the server started time with below command > uptime after invoking the lambda again?

Comment: So you've got 200 response can you kindly check the server started time with below command > uptime after invoking the lambda again?

Comment: You say that it works with `start_instances()` -- does that mean the instance was in a **Stopped** state? How are you confirming whether the reboot worked -- I don't think it appears in the system status, you would need to connect to the instance to know if it is working.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Thanks for your reply. Created a cloudtrail log, but it doesn't log any action.

Comment: @Prashanna I am monitoring the EC2 instances directly from the EC2 console. Uptime > 10 minutes when I perform the test.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No that was just a test I performed to see if any other actions were supported. Start and stop works, reboot no. Before performing the tests I boot the instance and leave it running for 10 minutes, all done from the EC2 console

Comment: But what do you mean by "It just refuses to work"? Are you saying that you were logged into the instance when the Reboot command was issued, and the connection to the instance continued without being logged out?

Comment: Correct. If I replicate the exact same conditions and issue a stop command then I am immediately logged out and the instance stops. If I issue the reboot command nothing, absolutely nothing, happens

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same code as you, just one step more for you to check:
Add the "RebootInstances" access right in your IAM account assigned for Lambda.
If you created IAM policy following the documentation, it will be like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ec2:Stop*",
        "ec2:Reboot*"   // <-----Add this
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```